# Backbone.js How do I clear model.validationError on successful validation

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I have a form that uses Backbone's model.validate function to validate the form. The form listens to the model's `change sync invalid` events, and renders in error state if the model has a `validationError` property. This works great when validation fails, but when it subsequently succeeds, the `validationError` object still exists.

I'm aware that this is the [expected behaviour](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validationError) (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validationError), but I need a way to run the error rendering code **only** when the previous validation fails *without* calling `model.isValid()`, because my validation code is quite complicated for some of the types of models that use this generic view.

```
render: function() {
    var html = '';

    // Error Row html
    if (this.model.validationError) {
        html += this.renderValidationErrors();
    }

    ...

    this.$el.html(html);

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Backbone when you (or Backbone) are doing `set`, `save` or `isValid` framework sets result of calling `validate` method to `validationError` attribute.

Method `validate` in your model should return `null` or `undefined` and this value will be set in `this.model.validationError` attribute.

if you have `validate` method than easiest way to return null if validation pass.

Example:

```
validate: function() {
    var errors = [];
    if (!this.get('name')) {
        errors.push({'name': 'Name is required'});
    }
    return errors.length ? errors : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that was part of the problem; the other part was that my validate code was calling `set`; not the best idea I've ever had. :)

Comment: I also would recommend to check this plugin for reactive validation https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation . I've used it many times and it works very good with declarative-style validation

Comment: This should be validate: function(attrs), and attrs.name instead of this.get('name') otherwise validating before actually setting the attributes doesn't work.  

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate